# How to compare date with current date for applying logic

Tags: javascript, date

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(date.now()>($("[id$=clear2]").val)+2){
    $("[id$=clear]").val("");
    $("[id$=clear2]").val("");// date value
    $("[id$=clear3]").val("");
    }
});
</script>
```

I want to check that current date(dd/mm/yyyy)  is greater than  date(dd/mm/yyyy)  value + 2 days .I was working several scenarios .that by removing if condition it is working fine .By using this it is not working well .Can you show some solution so that i can move forward

Comment: provide us fiddle link if possible

Comment: you can simple use moment,js and do your date time manipulate easily

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
    var d1 = '31/11/2015'.split('/');
    var d2 = '27/12/2015'.split('/');

    var date1 = new Date(d1[2],d1[1],d1[0]); // YYYY,MM,DD

    var date2 = new Date(d2[2],d2[1],d2[0]);
    var numOfDaysToAdd = 2;
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + numOfDaysToAdd);
    
    if (date1.getTime() < date2.getTime()) {
       alert('date1 is before date2');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working with dates in javascrip:**

*javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var today = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date(today);
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    $("#today").val(today.toUTCString());
    $("#tomorrow").val(tomorrow.toUTCString());
    $("#checkDate").click(function () {
        var newDate = new Date($("#today").val());
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 2);
        var parsedTomorrow = new Date($("#tomorrow").val());
        var comRes = newDate > parsedTomorrow;
        alert(comRes);
    });
});
```

*HTML*

```
<input type="text" id="today" />
<input type="text" id="tomorrow" />
<input type="button" id="checkDate" />
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/3bkp2LtL/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadate.html) to compare dates in javascript.